# Generic term for move in and move out

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am creating a title for a table that represents moving in and moving out activities for an apartment building, and I'm looking for something less clumsy than "Move Ins/Move Outs" - is there a more general term for this activity? Unfortunately in this context "Moves" is already taken as it represents the combination of a Move Out (of origin) and a Move In (to destination).

Comment: Perhaps *movements*.

Comment: Or just *moves.*

Answer (score 0):

A more general term would be "relocation" but I don't think that would work well for what you are describing. If it can be casual rather than formal, maybe something like "The Welcome / Farewell Checklist" might work...